# Angular 7 - Set the data source for the Select/dropdown box

Tags: angular, angular7, devextreme

I am querying a API and getting the data back in a array. I am not sure how to set the data source for the Select/dropdown box from the Data response back from the API. My model class is

```
 export class sProject {
  Id: string;
  prj_number: string;
  emp_number : string;
  }
```

My Component is like

```
 export class RFComponent implements OnInit {
    sList: sProject[];
    entityUrl = 'sDetail/GetByRP?Prj=345';

 constructor(service: DataService) {
  service.get<sProject[]>(this.entityUrl).subscribe(x => 
  {this.stList = x });
  }
   ngOnInit() {  }}
```

The data is in the `sList` array, I am not sure how I can set the datasource for my select/dropdown box

```
<div class="dx-fieldset">
  <div class="dx-field">
    <div class="dx-field-label">ShipTo Account</div>
    <div class="dx-field-value">
        <dx-select-box></dx-select-box>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I am using the devextreme library here, I am trying to see all the prj_number in the dropdown box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the devextreme [website](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/SelectBox/CustomizeDropDownButton/Angular/Light/)
Try this:

```
<dx-select-box [dataSource]="sList" displayExpr="prj_number "></dx-select-box>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Perfect it works . Do you know if there is anyway to show only distinct values?

Comment: try something like this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dcnpqo)